# Read text file in Swift

Tags: swift, text

I am trying to read a text file from the program, which is

```
 var name = String.stringWithContentsOfFile("test.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:nil)
```

(where text.txt is under project folder)

I also tried:

```
 var name = String.stringWithContentsOfFile("/Users/Michael/Desktop/test.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:nil)
```

(Directory)

And both of them return a nil value to me. I checked the file and make sure it is a txt file with UTF-8 code. Can someone help me?

Comment: The first thing *you* should do is to use the `error` parameter ...

Comment: Are you coding for iOS or OSX?

Comment: I read over the documents and had no idea how to declare an error object, would you please tell me how to use it? Thanks @MartinR

Comment: And sry forgot mention I'm doing IOS @AlbertoBarrera

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have that problem, because you've specified the path to the file as a string, while it should be a path object. Try the following example:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "txt")
var data = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

This example assumes that the file in question is located in your app bundle.

Comment: hi, thanks, I tried your method, it works! But I would have to add an explanation mark after path so that the code works. And I am not sure why it happens, would you help me again? @pda

Comment: String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) is DEPRECATED and does NOT work anymore with Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5.7 (Xcode 14):

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
        print(data)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```