# Swift read file, outputs data surrounded by Optional()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to read a .txt file from my Resource folder in a swift iOS project. The function is

```
class func readFile(){
        var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testfile", ofType:"txt")
        var dataout = NSString(contentsOfFile: filePath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        println(dataout)
    }
```

My text file is

**This is a test**

The console outputs

**Optional(This is a test
)**

I can't figure out what the Optional() is????

Comment: That doesn't explain why it is printing out 'Optional(...)'

Comment: That's just the `println` (`Printable` protocol really) representation of an optional value. If you unwrap the value first, it won't print the `Optional()` part.

Comment: [you can look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926536/read-text-file-in-swift/26581039#26581039)

Comment: var dataout = String(contentsOfFile: filePath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)! // try it like this and the answer for your question: optional means that you might get an error/nil or a string returned when trying to read it