# Issue opening file in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to read text from a file and I am currently using this statement to read from a file.

When I try to print the path it shows 'nil' and I am not sure why it is not opening the file since it prints the else statement. Can someone tell me how I can go about doing this possibly another way?

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "knapsack", ofType: "txt")
{
    print("File opened")
}
else
{
    print("failed to load file from bundle")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read text file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926536/read-text-file-in-swift)

Comment: Make sure the TextFile is in .txt format not a .rtf format

Comment: I made sure it is in txt format. For some odd reason it does not want to read the file. I deleted the txt file and re added it using the steps below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to add the text file in the product path that is located in **Library -> Developer -> Xcode -> Derived Data -> "Your Project" -> Build -> Products -> Debug**.

I added the file to this path and this solved issue and had no issue opening the file. I guess Xcode has two different paths that needs to have a file added.

Answer (score -1):

1- create a file named knapsack.txt

2- drag the file to project and select copy

[image]

[image]

3- reference the file as you currently do

see demo here [readFile](http://www.mediafire.com/file/uv9o99euri5q53k/readFile.rar)

Comment: where in the project would a text file need to be placed? I currently have it in the same folder as "main"

Comment: see file named mm.txt

Comment: Still getting the same error. I followed the steps exactly.

Comment: Yes. I made sure it was checked

Comment: Checked the name of the file they are the same. And  it only keeps printing the  failed to open from bundle portion.

Comment: Note that case has to be correct. If the file is name "Knapsack.txt" and you try to open it as "knapsack.txt", it will fail.

Comment: Which print statement is being displayed?